# increase numeric value of variable based on level of categorical variable

Tags: r, variables, dplyr

Don't see another question like this one. I've used mutate to create new variables, but can't find a tutorial that shows how to do this: I'm trying to add +2 to the hsi value if the con value is NALFD

```
con <- c('NALFD', 'NALFD', 'NALFD', 'NASH', 'NASHCC')
hsi <- c(45.71571, 37.09238, 48.89828, 46.37123, 39.8328)
df <- data.frame(con, hsi)
```

So hsi should be: 47.71571, 39.09238, 50.89828, 46.37123, 39.8328

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `if_else` -

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% mutate(hsi = if_else(con == 'NALFD', hsi + 2, hsi))
df
#     con      hsi
#1  NALFD 47.71571
#2  NALFD 39.09238
#3  NALFD 50.89828
#4   NASH 46.37123
#5 NASHCC 39.83280
```

Also in base R -

```
df <- transform(df, hsi = ifelse(con == 'NALFD', hsi + 2, hsi))
```

Comment: Not working with my full dataset with 158 rows m <-  m %>% dplyr::mutate(HSI = if_else(Indication == 'NALFD', HSI+ 2, HSI))
glimpse(m), 45.71571, 37.09238 - 37 should be 39, the first one is not NALFD

Comment: Seems using "" instead of '' around NAFLD did the trick. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ronak - you removed your comment. I wanted to respond. WHat was it again?

Comment: works, must have been a typo but here is a subset -- sub <-
        structure(list(Indication = c("NASH", "NAFLD", "NAFLD", "NAFLD", 
                                      "NAFLD"), HSI = c(45.7157137377985, 39.0923846783179, 50.8982846959234, 
                                                        48.3712321740023, 41.8328741965106)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                "tbl", "data.frame"))